# Centralized log files using Windows Server

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, windows-server-2008, logstash, kibana

I want to have a web interface for end-users in order to provide them the chance to monitor the log files from different servers using only the interface.

I found this proposal:

```
  http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-centralized
```

And this example for implementation process:

```
  http://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2013/11/19/collect-visualize-your-logs-logstash-elasticsearch-redis-kibana/
```

Generally as I know Redis is compatible with Linux OS. However My OSs are Windows Servers 2008.

Could be possible to use this solution? Any example would be more than helpful for me.

Thank you.

Comment: If my answer doesn't answer your question could you respond with more details otherwise please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

So far Redis do not support on window OS.

However, you can try to install this unofficial  [redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) which suggest on redis page.

Comment: Still have another broker: rabbitmq. http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/inputs/rabbitmq. You can try it.